# How do I get access to fixture_file_upload in a model test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

`fixture_file_upload` is a helper available in integration tests.

When testing a model method that deals with Active Storage, I need to get access to this helper. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

[As seen in the API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/FixtureFile.html), `fixture_file_upload` is a shortcut for `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.file_fixture_path, path), type)`.

So you can upload a file ready to test this way:

```
image = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.file_fixture_path, 'file.jpeg'), 'image/jpeg')
```

You then can **attach and persist** it to the model using the attach method:

```
model.attach image
```

Or just assigning it, so you can test things like `attachment_changes`. For example, in a `has_many` relationship:

```
model.images = [image]
```